# Github push error. Getting large file errors still after trying to track puppeteer chromium with git-lfs. Why is it even trying to upload this?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, puppeteer, chromium, git-lfs

I am trying to push my Node.js app which uses puppeteer2.1.1 into Github so I can then host on Azure. After trying to push I get these errors.

[image: error message after trying to push to git]

I tried using `git lfs` followed all the commands by tracking the files, which I believe needs to be `/.local-chromium` according to the error message. After trying to push again still failed.

Has anybody used puppeteer and uploading to GitHub ever run into the same problem? I am also confused as to why it is even going to the node_modules folder. I thought that was automatically ignored when pushing to git. Here is my code below.

index.js

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
require('dotenv').config();
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

function coronaInfoSearch(){

    puppeteer.launch({  
        headless:true
    }).then(async browser =>{


        //open new tab and go to specified url
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/');

        //select elements wanted 
        page.waitForSelector('td')
            .then(async function(){

                //var self explanatory 
                const njRowTotalCases =await page.$eval('table .even .sorting_1', element => element.innerHTML);
                const njRowName = await page.$eval('table .even td', element => element.innerHTML);
                const njRowActiveCases = await page.$eval('#usa_table_countries_today > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(6)', element => element.innerHTML);
                const njRowDeaths = await page.$eval('#usa_table_countries_today > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(4)' , element => element.innerHTML);

                var coronainfoOutput = "Total Cases:\n"+njRowTotalCases+"\n\n"+"Active Cases:"+njRowActiveCases+"\n\n"+"Total Deaths:"+njRowDeaths;
                //atring to be sent for outputting 
                var coronainfoOutputHeading="NJ COVID-19 Update\n----------------\n";

                //sent text message 
                client.messages
                  .create({
                     body: coronainfoOutputHeading + coronainfoOutput,
                     from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
                     to: process.env.ANT_NUMBER
                   })
                  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
            })
    });
};

schedule.scheduleJob("55 13 * * 0-6", function(){
    coronaInfoSearch();
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "coronawebscrap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "puppeteer":  "^2.1.1",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "twilio": "^3.41.1"
  }
}
```

.gitattributes

```
.local-chromium filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

### Edit

After putting node_modules/ under the .gitignore file, then adding to git repo, then committing, then pushing, I am still having same error.

**.gitignore**

```
.env
node_modules/
```

Git actions and errors:

[image: **git actions and errors**]

Answer (score 0):

You need a `.gitignore` file in the root of the repository as you don't want to be uploading the node_modules

Take a look at: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore

Comment: Hey razki, I did the recommended changes, then tried to push to Github and still had the same problems. I posted the error log in the edit. For some reason, it still tries to upload the node module. I feel like it has something to do with puppeteer maybe?

Comment: It will be conflicting with the `.gitattributes` file, why do you need that? - Shouldn't need to add those to files you're not going to be checking into git

Comment: hey, I deleted and went through the git process again with the same errors. Is there any way I can use git-lfs in order to bypass those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got assisted. But, as another advice,

```
`git lfs track "*.zip"`
```

should do the trick! Cheers! (Follow the guide on ([Git Large Files Page](https://git-lfs.github.com/))